# Is Dabi related to the Todoroki family

Tags: my-hero-academia

Is Dabi Endeavors oldest son Toya Todoroki? I need to know because google is not working.

Comment: related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/is-dabi-endeavors-son

Comment: Even though he has the similar quirk as the todorokis, is not confirmed to be a part of the family. (so far)